# why canvas drawImage method is scaling?

Tags: css, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a picture on a canvas with width 150px and height 150px with the following code. However, the picture seems to be scaling with the width and height attributes I set to the canvas (I set the width to 500px and height to 300px). Why the canvas is working this way? How can I draw an image on a canvas with an absolute size in px?

Thank you very much!

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Base</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var img = new Image();

        $(window).ready(function() {
            img.src = "./Images/img.jpg";;

            ctx = document.getElementById("main").getContext("2d");

            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150);
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="main" style="background-color:yellow; width:500px; height:300px; z-index:1; position:absolute;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the actual pixel resolution of your canvas, that is, set the number of rows and columns of pixels (by using the `width` and `height` attributes on the `canvas` tag).  Otherwise, you're just going to get a canvas with its default resolution scaled by the width and height as determined by your CSS.

Edit: Think about it this way.  When you place a canvas in the DOM, you are essentially declaring something like a manipulate-able image with a specific width and height in pixels.  Now that image can be scaled arbitrarily. So if you have a 200x200 canvas, but declare in the CSS that the canvas is 400px by 200px,   each pixel of the canvas is going to be rendered with a height of two pixels (with anti-aliasing). So any image drawn to that canvas is going to be twice as tall as it normally is.  So if you want the width and height of a pixel on the canvas to represent the with of a pixel as rendered on the screen **, you want to set the width and height to the actual number of pixels involved, instead of using CSS.

** Pixels may not literally represent a pixel on a screen. For instance, I'm writing this on as Surface Pro, which has dpi scaling active for many apps, otherwise application buttons would be really tiny and it'd be a bit hard to touch to activate. The width of the screen that my browser sees the width is 1920/1.5 = 1280.  I could turn this setting of for the browser, restart it, and it'd see the full 1920... now, how does that effect image rendering? I think the browser can render full at-true-pixel resolution images even with this setting; Windows is not just rendering some blurry-zoomed in version of the browser, but I'd have to do some research to see just actually what Windows in conjunction with the browser.

Comment: Clear enough! Thank you very much!